# setting up node application for production server using babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, production-environment, babeljs

I'm trying to get my first ever node app ready for a production server.

build and serve scripts I'm basing on that given by [babel](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server)

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --ignore public/",
    "build": "babel server.js -o server_compiled.js",
    "serve": "node server_compiled.js",
    "dev": "webpack -wd"
```

}

```
npm run build
```

works as expected

```
npm run serve
```

results in an error:

```
some/path/config.js:3

export default{
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

This is from a config file that I'm referencing in server.js for port host and db.

Do I build this file also or what have I done wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, I eventually figured out I had to compile all of the .js files in the app individually. I'm sure there must be automated way to do this but thought I'd leave the solution in case anyone can't find anything else.